# PHP array sort different ways

Tags: php

I export from MYSQL db different info that I put inside an array:

```
$info=array(
(ID,CALORIES,PROTEIN,CARBOS,FIBER),
...
);
ex: (1,270,24,12,5),(2,280,2,42,10),...
```

Then, further down the script, I need to get the IDs of the 3 products with the highest calories, of the 6 products with the highest result of 2xPROTEIN+3xCARBOS, etc for 5 charts.

How can I do such a sorting of the array to fill my different tables?

The function sort() only seems to work for a single-dimensioned array (if it works for my case, I don't know what would be the syntax). It also doesn't seem to work for my more advanced sortings (2*x+3*y)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even tho it is not exactly what you are asking, I would highly suggest you preparing your tables in mysql (using all formulas to sort, etc.). Mysql's main job is do various selections and sorting, I would leave the work for it. Moreover, advanced sorting in mysql is way easier than thinking of algorithms or functions in php :)

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
ORDER BY (2*PROTEIN+3*CARBOS) DESC
```

Easy as that and no headaches. Apply LIMIT 3 at the end to get the top 3. Update

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
```

to your more advanced query. If having difficulties in code you may try to wrap it up as a subquery as this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `type`='fruit' LIMIT 6) a
ORDER BY (2*PROTEIN+3*CARBOS) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: But if my db contains more than 2 million entries, I think performance-wise, I'd be better off with a PHP solution, don't you agree?

Comment: No, because you can specify sorting on a specific query, not on a whole table.

Comment: @Andrius Say I get my original results with $result3 = mysql_query($sql3), how would you "sort on a specific query" ?

Comment: That is the point - you sort before retrieving the data and the sorting is applied in query. For example: I will post it in the answer so it is nicer formatting. One sec.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I understand, but I need about 5 or 6 different kinds of sortings like that (with different formulas, not only ORDER BY (2*PROTEIN+3*CARBOS)..how would I order differently? I would need to requery various times?

Comment: Either way you will be accessing the data and using up memory, etc. In my opinion, it is probably just get the results in one go. Moreover, it's mysql's job to sort, not php's. If you are going to have 5 arrays of the same data and apply functions in php side, it won't be much of a win over doing it on mysql side not to mention mysql will do it faster for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_multisort()` to sort multidimensional arrays. The syntax allows for quite some flexibilty, see [the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort` function:

```
function cmp( $a, $b )
{ 
  if(  $a["calories"] *3+ $a["protein"]*2 ==   $b["calories"] *3+ $b["protein"]*2){ //do another comparison etc.. ; } 
  return ($a["calories"] *3+ $a["protein"]*2<   $b["calories"] *3+ $b["protein"]*2)) ? -1 : 1;
} 
usort($myarray,'cmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

`usort` is your friend here.

```
function sort2Protein3Carbo($a, $b)
{
    // Assuming protein is the 2nd value in your array and carbo the 3rd.
    $resA = 2 * $a[2] + 3 * $a[3];
    $resB = 2 * $b[2] + 3 * $b[3];

    if ($resA == $resB)
        return 0;

    return ($resA < $resB) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($info, "sort2Protein3Carbo");
```